# CSS Image animation works in all browsers BUT safari

Tags: html, css, image, css-animations

I am using CSS to flip images to make them look like they flip in.

This works in all browsers but safari. Please open this link in chrome or firefox where it appears correctly, then please open it in safari:

http://project-awesome.id-staging.com/SO-test/index.html

Here is my CSS:

### KEYFRAMES

```
@-moz-keyframes spin { 100% {opacity:1; -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg); } }
@-webkit-keyframes spin { 100% {opacity:1;  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg); } }
@keyframes spin { 100% {opacity:1;  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg); transform:rotateY(180deg); } }

@-moz-keyframes spin2 { 100% {opacity:1; -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg); } }
@-webkit-keyframes spin2 { 100% {opacity:1; transform:rotateY(-180deg); -webkit-transform-origin:100% 0 0; transform-origin:100% 0 0; } }
@keyframes spin2 { 100% {opacity:1; transform:rotateY(-180deg); -webkit-transform-origin:100% 0 0; transform-origin:100% 0 0; } }

@-moz-keyframes spin3 { 100% { opacity:1; transform:rotateX(-180deg); -webkit-transform-origin:0 100% 0; transform-origin:0 100% 0; } }
@-webkit-keyframes spin3 { 100% { opacity:1; transform:rotateX(-180deg); -webkit-transform-origin:0 100% 0; transform-origin:0 100% 0; } }
@keyframes spin3 { 100% { opacity:1; transform:rotateX(-180deg); -webkit-transform-origin:0 100% 0; transform-origin: 0 100% 0; } }

@-moz-keyframes spin5 { 100% { opacity:1; transform:rotateX(180deg); -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0 100% 0; transform-origin:100% 0 0 } }
@-webkit-keyframes spin5 { 100% { opacity:1; transform:rotateX(180deg); -webkit-transform-origin:0 0 100% 0; transform-origin:0 0 100% 0; } }
@keyframes spin5 { 100% { opacity:1; transform:rotateX(180deg); -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0 100% 0  ; transform-origin: 0 0 100% 0; } } 

@-moz-keyframes spin4 { 100% {opacity:1; -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg); } }
@-webkit-keyframes spin4 { 100% {opacity:1; transform:rotateY(-180deg); -webkit-transform-origin:100% 0 0; transform-origin:0 100% 0; } }
@keyframes spin4 { 100% {opacity:1; transform:rotateY(-180deg); -webkit-transform-origin:100% 0 0; transform-origin:0 100% 0; } }
```

### Each image flip:

```
.front-1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: -65px;
  top: 54px;
  width: 72px;
  height: 72px;
  opacity:0;

  -webkit-animation:spin2 0.5s 0.5s linear forwards;
  -moz-animation:spin2 0.5s 0.5s linear forwards;
  animation:spin2 0.5s 0.5s linear forwards;

}


.front-2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 7px;
  top: 54px;
  width: 72px;
  height: 72px;
  z-index:-94; 
  opacity:0;
  -webkit-animation:spin2 0.5s 1.2s linear forwards;
  -moz-animation:spin2 0.5s 1.2s linear forwards;
  animation:spin2 0.5s 1.2s linear forwards;

}

.front-3 {
  position: absolute;
  left: -65px;
  top: 374px;
  width: 72px;
  height: 72px;
  opacity:0;
  -webkit-animation:spin2 0.5s 1.5s linear forwards;
  -moz-animation:spin2 0.5s 1.5s linear forwards;
  animation:spin2 0.5s 1.5s linear forwards;
}

.front-4 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 7px;
  top: 374px;
  width: 72px;
  height: 72px;
  z-index:-95;
  opacity:0;
  -webkit-animation: spin2 0.5s 2.0s linear forwards;
  -moz-animation:spin2 0.5s 2.0s linear forwards;
  animation:spin2 0.5s 2.0s linear forwards;
}

.front-5 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 79px;
  top: 446px;
  width: 72px;
  height: 72px;
  opacity:0;

}

.front-6 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 79px;
  top: 374px;
  width: 72px;
  height: 72px;
  z-index:-96;
  opacity: 0;

  -webkit-animation:spin3 0.5s 2.5s linear forwards;
  -moz-animation:spin3 .0.5s 2.5s linear forwards;
  animation:spin3 0.5s 2.5s linear forwards;
}

.front-7 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 79px;
  top: 518px;
  width: 72px;
  height: 72px;
  z-index:-99;
  opacity:0;


  -webkit-animation:spin4 0.5s 3.5s linear forwards;
  -moz-animation:spin4 0.5s 3.5s linear forwards;
  animation:spin4 0.5s 3.5s linear forwards;
}



.front-8 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 79px;
  top: 446px;
  width: 72px;
  height: 72px;
  z-index:-98;
  opacity:0;

  -webkit-animation:spin3 0.5s 3.0s linear forwards;
  -moz-animation:spin3 0.5s 3.0s linear forwards;
  animation:spin3 0.5s 3.0s linear forwards;
}








/* BACK IMAGE CLASSES */

.back-1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 79px;
  top: 54px;
  width: 72px;
  height: 72px;
  opacity:0;

  -webkit-animation:spin 0.5s 7s linear forwards;
  -moz-animation:spin 0.5s 7s linear forwards;
  animation:spin 0.5s 7s linear forwards;
}

.back-2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 79px;
  top: 54px;
  width: 72px;
  height: 72px;
  opacity:0;
}

.back-3 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 79px;
  top: 374px;
  width: 72px;
  height: 72px;
  opacity:0;
  -webkit-animation:spin4 0.5s 5.5s linear forwards;
  -moz-animation:spin4 0.5s 5.5s linear forwards;
  animation:spin4 0.5s 5.5s linear forwards;
}

.back-4 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 79px;
  top: 374px;
  width: 72px;
  height: 72px;
  opacity:0;
  -webkit-animation:spin5 0.5s 6s linear forwards;
  -moz-animation:spin5 0.5s 6s linear forwards;
  animation:spin5 0.5s 6s linear forwards;
}

.back-5 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 7px;
  top: 446px;
  width: 72px;
  height: 72px;
  opacity:0;
}

.back-6 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 79px;
  top: 446px;
  width: 72px;
  height: 72px;
  opacity:0;
  -webkit-animation:spin5 0.5s 4.5s linear forwards;
  -moz-animation:spin5 0.5s 4.5s linear forwards;
  animation:spin5 0.5s 4.5s linear forwards;
}


.back-7 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 7px;
  top: 518px;
  width: 72px;
  height: 72px;
  opacity:0;
  z-index:80;

  -webkit-animation:spin 0.5s 4s linear forwards;
  -moz-animation:spin 0.5s 4s linear forwards;
  animation:spin 0.5s 4s linear forwards;
}


.back-8 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 7px;
  top: 518px;
  width: 72px;
  height: 72px;
  opacity:0;
  z-index:-81;
  -webkit-animation:spin2 0.5s 5s linear forwards;
  -moz-animation:spin2 0.5s 5s linear forwards;
  animation:spin2 0.5s 5s linear forwards;


}
```

Any ideas are highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

you forgot the `-webkit-` prefix in some of your transforms in the `@-webkit-keyframes` blocks.

i wont go over everything, but you should lookup sections like this:

```
@-webkit-keyframes spin2 {
    100% {
        opacity:1;
        transform:rotateY(-180deg);
        -webkit-transform-origin:100% 0 0;
        transform-origin:100% 0 0;
    }
}
```

and add the `-webkit-` prefix to the rotation transformation as well.